# Need Regex explanation

Tags: regex

I need to understand the syntax of the following regular expression to frame my own letters for testing:

```
3[4,7][0-9]{2}[-, ]?[0-9]{2}([0-9]{4})[-, ]?([0-9]{5})
```

I'm trying to understand American credit card numbers so I can validate credit card numbers. A possible valid input should be the number 378282246310005.

Comment: What is this expression used for? What is your use case? What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: What does "framing your own letters for testing" mean

Comment: What a strange regex. Are you sure you've got the `[…]` vs `{…}` right?

Answer (score 4):

```
3          - Match a single "3"
[4,7]      - Match one of "4", "," or "7"
[0-9]{2}   - Match 2 characters where each character is in the range '0' to '9'
[-, ]?     - Match an optional "-", "," or space
[0-9]{2}   - Match 2 characters where each character is in the range '0' to '9'
([0-9]{4}) - Match 4 characters where each character is in the range '0' to '9', 
           - and make the results available in $1
[-, ]?     - Match an optional "-", "," or space
([0-9]{5}) - Match 5 characters where each character is in the range '0' to '9',
           - and make the results available in $2
```

It's possible that the `[4,7]` and `[-, ]` are meant to be a comma-separated list of terms, but that isn't how character sets (`[...]`) works - You don't have to separate matchable characters by commas. They very likely should be `[47]`, and `[- ]` respectively. That is, if you want to match "a" *or* "b" *or* "c", you would write `[abc]` and **not** `[a,b,c]`.

The sections wrapped in parenthesis denote match groups; The specific sub-strings matched by these groups are made available (typically through variables `$1` or `$2`, or some "matches" array) if the pattern matches.

Comment: Note, too, that the entries in parentheses are the two match groups, which the regex engine will return along with the full match. Those digits are probably particularly significant.

Comment: [4,7] - Match "4", "," or "7"  In this line comma doesnt match for credit card.  i used this card 378282246310005

Comment: And, now that you mention it, I'm guessing the commas are accidental, and that the author thought they were required delimiters in a character class. They should probably be removed.

Comment: @user1209784 They match *one* of those three characters, "4", "," *or* "7". Your sample number has a "7" in that place, so it matches.

Answer (score 1):

Starts with a 3: `3`

Followed by a 4, a comma, or a 7: `3[4,7]`

Followed by exactly 2 digits (`{2}` means exactly 2): `3[4,7][0-9]{2}`

Possibly followed by a dash, comma or a space (`?` means optional): `3[4,7][0-9]{2}[-, ]?`

Followed by exactly 2 digits: `3[4,7][0-9]{2}[-, ]?[0-9]{2}`

Gotta dash off, my taxi's just arrived, so someone else can finish that off :)